# Why do creases appear when I turn on subdivision divider?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

So I'm mid-way through modelling a head, and so I decided to turn on subdivision surface modifier to see what it would look like with smoother geometry, but it created some weird creasing effects (not sure what else to call it) on the head, and I have no clue why.

[image]

This is without the modifier on:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: This is probably and as often due to inverted normals. In edit mode use Shift+N. If not try to remove doubled vertices (merge by distance) Alt+M.

Comment: Check if there are no double vertices.

Comment: The normals were inverted; thanks! It's fixed now